# VB.NET code formatting tool

Tags: vb.net, coding-style, code-formatting

Does anybody knows good VB.NET code formatting tool? By code formatting I mean rearranging class members by type, scope and alphabetically, maybe customized.

Every tool I found is for C# only, no VB.NET. Only tool that can do that is MZ-Tools, which have some major flaws and NArrange, which is obsolete and can not arrange new VB.NET language features.

Comment: I just use outlining to make it easier to rearrange code regions.

Comment: I hate regions, they only force you to constantly collapse and expand.

Comment: I as referring to the more generic "region" e.g. Sub() Function(), Class() etc.

Comment: Anyway thats not what I need to maintain crystal clear code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **DevExpress CodeRush for Roslyn**

(Visual Studio 2015+)